# Tabela em ficheiro SVG

Tags: php, svg

Crio um ficheiro SVG em PHP. Queria escrever no ficheiro uma tabela, para depois poder mostrar. Utilizei isto, mas nao mostra a tabela quando abro com um programa de edição.

```
fwrite($hndl, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>\n");
fwrite($hndl, "<svg width='297mm' height='210mm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\n");
fwrite($hndl, "<foreignobject x='10' y='10' width='100%' height='150'><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> ");
fwrite($hndl, "<table><tr><td>".$datelog."</td><td>".$nomcourbe."</td></tr><tr><td>".$login."</td><td>Pilotor</td></tr></table>\n");
fwrite($hndl, "</body></foreignobject>");
fwrite($hndl, "</svg>\n");                                                                              
fclose($hndl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário informar o namespace do XML que você deseja importar por meio do atributo `requiredExtensions` da tag `foreignobject`, e não apenas na primeira tag daquele XML específico:

```
<foreignobject x='10' y='10' width='100%' height='150' requiredExtensions='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'></body>
</foreignobject>
```